# Enter and Leave animation in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent

In my qml application there is content area "Item" and it have a "loader" for load qml file.

I want to implement leave and enter animation effect

For example my current source of loader is "First.qml" when i set source other qml file(second.qml). "First.qml" should fade out and "second.qml" will be fade in.

How should i achieve this?

I tried following code it animate only the second.qml. When we set source "first.qml" disappears. I want to give a fadeout animation to intial qml also ("first.qml")

```
 Loader{
            id:contentLoader
            source: "First.qml"

            onSourceChanged: animation.running = true

                    NumberAnimation {
                        id: animation
                        target: contentLoader.item
                        property: "opacity"
                        from: 0
                        to: 1
                        duration: 1000
                        easing.type: Easing.bezierCurve
                    }

        }
//button click
 Button{
                    text:modelData
                    width:100
                    height: parent.height

                    onClicked: {

                         contentLoader.setSource("Second.qml")


                    }


                }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit your question to show code that you already have

Comment: @teh_raab updated the question with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use [`StackView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html), since it has support for custom animations.

Using it's `replace` function, you could change the item being shown.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id : root
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible:true

    Component {
        id: lightblueRectangleComponent
        Rectangle {
            color: "lightblue"
            Button {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "replace"
                onClicked: stackView.replace(orangeRectangleComponent)
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: orangeRectangleComponent
        Rectangle {
            color: "orange"
            Button {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "replace"
                onClicked: stackView.replace(lightblueRectangleComponent)
            }
        }
    }

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: lightblueRectangleComponent

        replaceEnter: Transition {
            PropertyAnimation {
                property: "opacity"
                from: 0
                to:1
                duration: 200
                easing.type: Easing.OutQuad
            }
        }
        replaceExit: Transition {
            PropertyAnimation {
                property: "opacity"
                from: 1
                to:0
                duration: 200
                easing.type: Easing.InQuad
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..This is what i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the way i see it is you have two main options..

1)  Use a [SequentialAnimation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qml-sequentialanimation.html) that fades out the first view, loads in the second then fades it in with something like..

```
SequentialAnimation {
    id: switchContentAnimation

    //Fade out first view
    NumberAnimation {
        target: contentLoader
        property: "opacity"
        duration: 1000
        from: 0
        to: 1
    }

    //Switch view
    ScriptAction { script: contentLoader.setSource("Second.qml"); }

    //Fade new view back in
    NumberAnimation {
        target: contentLoader
        property: "opacity"
        duration: 1000
        from: 0
        to: 1
    }
}
```

This method would result in the area being blank for a fraction of a second.  Whereas as second option would be..

2) Cross-fade by adding in a second Loader and then when you select the button you cross-fade on opacity.  This could look something like..

```
property bool activeView: false //false: first, true: second
Loader{
    id:contentLoaderOne
    source: "First.qml"
    onOpacityChanged: {
        if(opacity == 0) {
            //unload this loaders source to save memory
        }
    }
}
Loader{
    id:contentLoaderTwo
    onOpacityChanged: {
        if(opacity == 0) {
            //unload this loaders source to save memory
        }
    }
}
ParallelAnimation {
    id: switchContentAnimation
    NumberAnimation {
        target: contentLoaderOne
        properties: "opacity"
        duration: 1000
        to: (activeView) ? 1 : 0
    }
        NumberAnimation {
        target: contentLoaderTwo
        properties: "opacity"
        duration: 1000
        to: (!activeView) ? 1 : 0
    }
}

//button click
Button{
    text:modelData
    width:100
    height: parent.height
    onClicked: {
        if(activeView) {
            //switch to second view..
            contentLoaderTwo.setSource("Second.qml")
        }
        else {
            //switch back to first view..
            contentLoaderOne.setSource("First.qml")
        }
        activeView = !activeView;
        switchContentAnimation.start()
    }
}
```

There may be errors in this as not in a position to run the code right now!